# c ncurses, window border broblem

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

After some investigation I'm found that this is not border problem, but problem of horizontal lines.

```
#include<ncurses.h>

main() {
    initscr();
    mvhline(7, 10, '=', 4);
    mvhline(8, 10, '=', 5);
    mvhline(9, 10, '=', 6);
    mvhline(10, 10, '=', 7);
    mvhline(11, 10, '=', 8);
    refresh();
    endwin();
}
```

And output

```
      ====    
      =====   
      ======  
      =       
      =
```

PuTTY, SLES 12. ncurses-5.6-90.55

Encoding, keyboard emulation and LC_* enviroment variables do not make difference

Question is simple:

Why is horizontal part of border is only 1 symbol and how to make it right size

Comment: Was there a question?

Comment: @PaulRooney Question is simple. Why is horizontal part of border is only 1 symbol. An how to make it right size.

Comment: @n.m. post updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem.

Problem in enviroment variable TERM

```
export TERM=ansi
```

hline work fine only in length range 0-7

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Don't work at all

```
export TERM=vt100
```

With vt100 all work fine